# Use of definition of limit to prove $\lim_{x→2} \dfrac{x}{x^2-2}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I know that by definition I have to prove that $$\lim_{x→2}\dfrac{x}{x^2−2}=1⟺∀ϵ>0,∃δ>0,\, 0<|x−2|<δ⟹\left|\frac{x}{x^2−2}−1\right|<ϵ.$$

I have:
$\left|\dfrac{-x^2+x+2}{x^2-2}\right|= \left|\dfrac{-(x^2-x-2)}{x^2-2}\right|= \left|\dfrac{-(x^2-x+1-3)}{x^2-2}\right|=$
$\left|\dfrac{-(x-1)^2+3}{x^2-2}\right|$.

So, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Use $(x^2-x-2)=(x-2)(x+1)$

Comment: BTW, you have an error in your last line. $-(x^2-x-2)\ne-(x-1)^2+3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $-(x^2-x-2)=-(x-2)(x+1)$ and that therefore$$\frac x{x^2-2}-1=-(x-2)\frac{x+1}{x^2-2}.$$Besides, if $|x-2|<\frac12$, then $\frac32<x<\frac52$ and therefore $\frac14<x^2-2<\frac{17}4$; in particular, $|x^2-2|>\frac14$. On the other hand, $\frac52<x+1<\frac72$; in particular, $|x+1|<\frac72$. So,\begin{align}\left|-(x-2)\frac{x+1}{x^2-2}\right|&=|x-2|\frac{|x+1|}{|x^2-2|}\\&<|x-2|\frac{7/2}{1/4}\\&=14|x-2|.\end{align}Therefore, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\min\left\{\frac\varepsilon{14},\frac12\right\}$, and then$$|x-2|<\delta\implies\left|\frac x{x^2-2}-1\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: I don't understand how you say that $3<x<5$, because if you do $|x-2|<1$ you have 1<x<3.

Comment: I've edited my answer and I suppose that it is correct now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think you meant to write $|x-2|<\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Oops! Sure I did! It's done now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think you want to write $\dfrac{1}{4}<x^2-2<\dfrac{17}{4}$.

Comment: Yes. That was a typo.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can you explain me how do you get this ...<14|x-2|? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. That $14$ is $\frac{7/2}{1/4}$.

Comment: I have a question, when you say $|x^2-2|>\dfrac{1}{4}$ then $\dfrac{1}{|x^2-2|}<4$. Also, you have that |x+1|<$\dfrac{7}{2}$. So, when you have narrow down, you have that |x-2| $\dfrac {| x+1 |} { | x^2-2 | }<\dfrac{7}{8} |x-2| $. Am I right?

Comment: Almost. Since $|x+2|<\frac72$ and $\frac1{|x^2-2|}<4$, then$$|x-2|\left|\frac{x+1}{x^2-2}\right|<|x-2|\times\frac72\times4=14|x-2|.$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116864/discussion-between-luisa-fernanda-rojas-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Answer (score 0):

Two points: 1) It's often much easier to deal with $x\to 0$ than $x\to c\neq 0$; and  2) you may want to avoid fractions whenever you can.

So let's denote $d=x-2$ and prove $\lim_{d\to 0} \dfrac{d+2}{(d+2)^2-2} = 1$.

$$
\left| \dfrac{d+2}{(d+2)^2-2} - 1 \right|=\left| \dfrac{d+2-d^2-4d-2}{d^2+4d+2} \right| = \left| d \right| \left| \dfrac{d+3}{d^2+d+2} \right|
$$

If $|d|<1, |d+3| \le |d| + 3<4$. Also note $|d^2+d+2|=\left(d+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{7}{4} > 1$.

Therefore, if $|d| < \delta = \min(1, \dfrac{1}{4} \varepsilon )$
$$\left| d \right| \left| \dfrac{d+3}{d^2+d+2} \right| < \dfrac{1}{4} \varepsilon \cdot \dfrac{4}{1} = \varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just use the definition: you need to verify that
$$\Bigg|\frac{x}{x^2-2}-1\Bigg| < \epsilon$$
gives you a neighbourhood of $2$.

This means to solve

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x}{x^2-2}-1 < \epsilon \\\\
\dfrac{x}{x^2-2}-1 > -\epsilon
\end{cases}
$$

Solve this and you will get

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{2\epsilon-4}{\epsilon-1}} < x < \sqrt{\dfrac{-2\epsilon-4}{-\epsilon-1}}$$

Which, being $\epsilon$ small ad libitum, gives you $2 < x < 2$.